# Android: Different Overflow Options for Different fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am using Navigation drawer which has 2 options.
When i click on first option, A fragment opens with overflow options in toolbar as follows:
[image]

When I click on second option, B fragment opens with overflow options in toolbar as follows:
[image]

Now, A Fragment and B fragment has same toolbar options in overflow menu **but i need different toolbar options in overflow menu for different fragments.**
I am making toolbar and its menu options in main activity from which which both fragment starts based on click of navigation drawer.
I know the above implementation is not correct with respect to my desired result 
Any idea how to achieve the result.

Comment: you need to implement oncreateoptionmenu() in each fragment(instead of activity) and apply different menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can make different menu xml files and load those in the fragments onCreateMenuOptions instead of the loading the menu's in the activity's onCreateMenuOptions.